# Utilising package versions that would play nicely with an outdated R version

Tags: r, package, version

I would like to have a possibility of installing versions of packages that would correspond to precisely defined version of **R**. For example:

```
paste(R.version$major, R.version$minor, sep = ".")
```

will give me current version **3.3.0**. However, let's assume that I'm working on a version **3.0.0** and I would like to install packages that were build utilising  that version. So if the version **3.0.0** is from *April 2013* and I'm interested in installing [rjava](/questions/tagged/rjava) package, I would like to install version [**0.9-4**](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rJava/) that was from the same period.

The [`versions`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/versions/index.html) package provides interface for accessing historical versions of a package:

```
>> versions::available.versions('rJava')
$rJava
   version       date available
1    0.9-8 2016-01-07      TRUE
2    0.9-7 2015-07-29      TRUE
```

## Practical implementation

In practice, I'm interested in building a mechanism that would install the packages that would play only with the give **R** version, so in the function:

```
tediousInstall <- function(pkg) {
    # Check R version
    version <- paste(R.version$major, R.version$minor, sep = ".")
    # How to efficiently choose the package version
}
```

I'm interested in building a mechanism that would identify the suitable package version depending on the utilised **R** version. One potential approach could involve reading the dates from `versions::available.versions(pkgs = "rJava")` and date matching version with the current **R** version.

### Question

Consequently my question boils down to:
*Is there a smarter way of doing this instead of having to "date match" packages and **R** versions?*

Comment: Not directly an answer, but the package `packrat` can help with package version management

Comment: @RichardTelford Thanks for showing the interest; I'm aware of packrat, but to me, this package makes more sense in managing projects across multiple environments (however it also easy to increase the folder size to a an unmanageable size). In practical terms, I'm looking for a quick solution to install the versions of certain packages that I need, which would correspond with the given R version. I reckon that it may file in case of some packages but that's OK. What I want to know boils down to whether there is an efficient way of doing that, other than date by date matching.

Comment: Also not an answer, but the revolution analytics people (now MS) host a daily snapshot of CRAN, so for some versions of R, you could pull from there. I don't know offhand how far back these snapshots go. On a semi-related note, R x.y.max(n) (eg, 2.15.3, 3.0.3, 3.1.3, 3.2.5) versions are maintenance releases, so packages are built for them even when a newer version of R has been released. This began around 2.14. But I'm not sure if this support ends after a certain number of maintenance versions are released.

Comment: @lmo  Thanks for the valid contribution. Daily CRAN snapshots could save me a little time but I would still have to faff around with figuring the date for R version. If push came to shove I could build a primitive data frame within a function but it looks like a convoluted way of doing things that, in my humble opinion, are not super exotic.